# DJANGO - upload image stored locally to model ImageField attribute

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have my images downloaded inside the subroot `images` in my `media` folder and I'm trying to generate new models which will contain the photo inside the `images` folder. This is what my model and my view look like:

```
class Post(models.Model):
   ...
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images", blank=True, null=True)
```

```
def generate_posts(request):
    for i in range(20):
        title_ = f'title{i}'
        body_ = f'text for post number : {i}'
        author_ = f'author{i}'
        network_ = randomize_social()
        post = Post(title=title_, body=body_, author=author_, social_network=network_)
        if randomize_picture():
            post.image.save("logo.png", File("images/svante.jpg"), save=True)
        else:
            post.image = None
        post.save()

    areGenerated = True
    return render(request, "posts/generate_posts.html", {'areGenerated':areGenerated})
```

The `logo.png` file is created inside the `images` folder, but it's blank, 0kb size and when I follow the `/generateposts` url, I receive this error message:

```
AttributeError at /generateposts
'str' object has no attribute 'read'
```

What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Did you try,  post.image = File("images/svante.jpg") and then post.save() ?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It still doesn't work, I get an error saying that `The 'image' attribute has no file associated with it.`

Answer (score 0):

Did you make changes to your settings file? you need to make changes such as
    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
    MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
and don't forget to add these to your urls:

```
from . import views, settings
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import static
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns


urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```